# How to calculate distribution return for ETF?

Tags: etf, calculation, rate-of-return

I'm trying to calculate Growth and Distribution returns for `ASX:VGS` for 2021 based on historical data, but the results do not match what's published.

[Here](https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/detail/8212/performance) I can see that in the 2021 Calendar year it had 27.11% Growth returns and 2.50% Distribution return.

I took [prices data](https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/detail/8212/prices-and-distributions#HISTORICAL_PRICES_MULTI_TABLE) and [distributions data](https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/detail/8212/prices-and-distributions#MF_DISTRIBUTION_HISTORY_TABLE) and keep getting different results no matter how I calculate.

For example, for Growth returns, I used this simple formula: `(end - start) / start`, where `start = NAV at 31 Dec 2020` and `end = NAV at 31 Dec 2021`.

Results in `($106.5669 - $83.9048) / $83.9048 = 27.01%`, which is not equal to `27.11%` on their [website](https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/detail/8212/performance).

The same goes for Distribution return, but I guess there are more options to calculate it.
First, I took all distributions that had a `Payable date` in 2021:
`40.335853 + 31.558398 + 81.302814 + 34.259378 = 187.456443` cents per unit. And the NAV unit price at the beginning of 2021 (04 Jan 2021 is the first price available) was `$83.2145`.

So, using the formula `187.456443 / 83.2145 = 2.25%` which is again not the same as `2.50%` on the [website](https://www.vanguard.com.au/personal/products/en/detail/8212/performance).

I've tried different variations, taking price one day before, one day after, calculating distribution return using NAV at the time of distribution, etc. Can't get the same numbers...

What am I doing wrong?

Stuff that I didn't try yet:

- Calculate average or weighted NAV on 1st Jan, based on the price on 31st Dec and 4th Jan
- Use some kind of averaging for distribution returns

Comment: See answers to previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919718/financial-python-library-that-has-xirr-and-xnpv-function - allow for reinvestment of distributions. Once you work out the calculations, financial years are better for your purposes.

Comment: @flywire thank you! I've tried FY21, got `(96.7508-77.4472)/77.4472 = 24.92%` instead of `24.90%` advertised for Growth returns. Also, xirr and xnpv functions are only applicable to Distribution returns, right? Since there are no cashflow events in Growth returns..

Comment: Standard practice is to use daily closing prices. I'd send the question to Vangard to find out the exact calculation. xirr and xnpv can be used on values (closing price optionally with distributions) between two dates, say calculate 30 Jun each year, 3yr, 5yr, 10yr, since inception etc. portfolio-performance.info/en is OK for a general app.

Comment: @flywire XIRR is a true discovery for me, thank you! However, I'm still having trouble getting the exact advertised Total Return by NAV... Here's my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MlicaEm7pSDeCDXlGd9nYcKlJR9v74DToiKyBT7JslE/edit?usp=sharing And also I don't quite understand how XNPV should be used... I don't really have a target discount rate, and if I use 0% - then it's simply adds everything up.

Comment: [XNPV](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xnpv-function-1b42bbf6-370f-4532-a0eb-d67c16b664b7) returns the net present value for a schedule of cash flows that is not necessarily periodic. It's part of [economic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost%E2%80%93benefit_analysis). There is always a discount rate because an amount today is worth more than the same amount in the future. The discount rate (or opportunity cost) of money could be inflation or the cost of a loan (which might be less if tax-deductible). So, for example, buy a house now or enter into a contract with a builder?